# curl request to guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

how convert this curl request

curl request

```
curl -L -F 'Request={"APIRequests":
[{"Verb":"UploadModelRelease","AuthToken":"","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Smith","Gender
":"0","AgeGroup":"1","Ethnics":"0","Country":"44"}]}' -F
'PropertyRelease=@Documents/jamie.pdf' https://api2.dreamstime.com/api/
```

to guzzlehttp request

guzzlecode

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', "https://api2.dreamstime.com/api/",[
  'json'=>[
    'APIRequests' => [
            [
              "Verb" => "UploadRelease",
              "AuthToken" => $this->getAccessToken(),//token
              "ModelRelease" => $file,//file path
              "FirstName" => $firstName,
              "LastName" => $lastName,
              "Gender" => $gender,
              "Country" => $country,
              "AgeGroup" => $ageGroup,
              "Ethnics" => $ethnics,
            ],
        ],
  ]
]);
```

error
"please upload a release file"

Comment: Hi. What have you tried?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy 
i added my code

Comment: Please share only the relevant code, we dont need to see all of it

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy so good ?

Comment: the guzzle code does not match your curl

Comment: I did not understand what you want to say @bhucho

Comment: I guess you are also sending a file, guzzle does not accept file like that, I will write an example

Comment: @bhucho i sending modelrelease.jpg file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a query closest to the curl request, as curl request has a -F with file that means that it is sending file, you will need multipart. As I have not tested so I can't guarantee that it will work though

```
/**
 curl -L -F 'Request={"APIRequests":
[{"Verb":"UploadModelRelease","AuthToken":"","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Smith","Gender
":"0","AgeGroup":"1","Ethnics":"0","Country":"44"}]}' -F
'PropertyRelease=@Documents/jamie.pdf' https://api2.dreamstime.com/api/

*/
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', "https://api2.dreamstime.com/api/",[
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'Request',
            'contents' => '{
                            "APIRequests":
                                [{"Verb":"UploadModelRelease","AuthToken":"","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Smith","Gender
                                ":"0","AgeGroup":"1","Ethnics":"0","Country":"44"}]
                            }' // place your json_encode here inplace of above
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'PropertyRelease',
            'contents' => fopen("/path/to/file", "r")
        ]
    ]
]);
```